# How to display events from all calendars in django schedule?

Tags: django, calendar, schedule

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to use django-schedule to my first project. I couldn't figure out how to change the following code to display all events in all calendars:

```
get_events(request, calendar):
    return calendar.event_set.all()
```

The code above simply displays all events of one particular calendar.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
from schedule.models import Event

Event.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My problem now is how to return all these events so that they can be displayed in one calendar. `return Event.objects.all()` is not working. Please help.

Comment: I used the operator | on my querysets and everything is working fine now.